# Instagram Login Permissions Review Basic vs Public_Content

Tags: ios, instagram-api

I'm a bit confused, at first I requested for basic and public_content permissions because I believed thats how I can view both my own images and other peoples' images on the app i'm pushing to the appstore.

However Instagram declined and say I didn't need it and that I only needed basic login permissions to view images. Now images for my friends no longer show up and its not a code issue because I can still see my own images.

Can I get a clarification of basic vs public_content permissions and if I'm doing this wrong from someone who has gone through the instagram review process? I've consulted the documentation many times and it seems as if I need public_content permission and reviewed several times but they always give us basic permissions.

Comment: quick way to hack this if u only have basic permission is to save the access token of each user who connects to ur app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to document what I did instead.

So for each user who logins and approves of Instagram access (by logging in on Instagram in my app using a webView and giving me the access token) I store their access token on a database and everytime that user comes up I grab the user's access token to request for their most recent media.

However this is really just me playing around and I'm not sure if:

a) Instagram refreshes the access token

b) This is explicitly allowed by Instagram, think I saw on its guidelines that this might be not allowed behaviour

and thus will need clarification on those above points if anyone else has a clue but this current method works for now for those wondering.

Comment: BTW Instagram doesnt allow us public_content permission, they only allow it if your users are brands and companies etc. and not regular people.